# Conversion Tracking accumulate

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I am working on Conversion Tracking through Marketing Cloud and have been able to populate the report with the data I am looking for except for values that I set as `accumulate = false` do not appear in the report.

When I set those values as `accumulate = true` they appear in the report but makes the report essentially worthless due to the fact that I am passing an OrderID whose value is adding billions of dollars in "sales" to the "Email Send Total".

Here is the `<data_set>` portion:

`<data_set>
  <data amt="50" unit="OrderID" accumulate="false"/>';
  <data amt="500" unit="Dollars" accumulate="true"/>';
  <data amt="500" unit="Units" accumulate="false"/>';
</data_set>`

Has anyone been able to figure out how to add `accumulate=false` and still have a value appear on the report?

Comment: Hey Michael - I'm not sure i fully understand the use case. You're saying that accumulate = false doesn't appear, but that order id messes it up. How can that be, when that line is accumulate = false? Also, how / where are you populating this data? in the links? or data fed back into the MC ?

Comment: Did anybody find a solution to this? Looking into implementing Conversion Tracking that can report on $ amount of the sale, but the only posts I've come across that are asking about amounts have been left unanswered.

Any insights or resources you can provide to help demystify this would be much appreciated!